# Объединить [бан] и [блокировку]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, мета

Есть метка [бан](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd) и более распростанённая и развёрнутая [блокировка](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0). Предлагаю синонимизировать [бан](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd) и сделать основной [блокировка](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синоним назначил. Основная метка [блокировка](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Comment: Не будет ли это название конфликтовать с заблокированными вопросами?

Comment: @alexolut, для заблокированных вопросов нужна метка [блокировка-вопросов] или типа того ([защищенные-вопросы]?).

Comment: @alexolut Я сперва не понял ваш вопрос. Можно будет в будущем сделать метку [tag:историческая-блокировка], мы же её так и называем. Но поскольку меткой [tag:блокировка] ни разу не воспользовались не по назначению — это пока разговор о чисто гипотетической ситуации.